# Uninstalled openssl-libs by accident, how do I reinstall it

Tags: centos, yum, openssl

I accidently uninstalled `openssl-libs` on a **CentOS 6.4** server. I still have an active SSH terminal session open, but I can't `wget` to download the openssl rpm. Yum won't work either, requires openssl.

Any ideas?

Comment: Grab a copy from another computer. Though you'll probably end up having to reinstall the OS. How did you manage to do this? `yum` should not allow you to remove a critical library like this.

Comment: How do I get the rpm onto the server? I don't have physical access, and SCP won't work (requires openssl-libs).

Comment: Get access to the console.

Comment: I have console access, where would the openssl-libs rpm be?

Comment: On the CentOS 6.5 DVD that you're going to use to update the system with.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same problem. I followed these steps and resolved it: https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-centos-6-centos-7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nc` (netcat) to transfer the RPM file to the system and do a `rpm -i` to install the package.

To do this you need to start netcat on both ends (your local workstation and the host in question). On the receiving end you would start netcat in listening mode first:

```
nc -l -p 2342 > openssl.rpm
```

This will start netcat listening (`-l`) on port `2342` (`-p 2342`) and writing what it receives to `openssl.rpm`.

Then on the sender side (ie. your local workstation) start sending the file over with the following command:

```
nc -w 5 DestinationHost 2342 < openssl.rpm
```

This will read the file `openssl.rpm` from the current folder, and start sending it to `DestinationHost` on port `2342`.

After the transfer has finished you should have a file on the target system called openssl.rpm which you can install with `rpm -i` as usual

Comment: Some more details would be helpful.

Comment: This won't always work; on CentOS/RHEL 7.x `nc` is linked against libssl.so and libcrypto.so. On CentOS/RHEL 6.x `nc` isn't though so it would work specifically for that version.